# ID3D11DeviceContext::Map slow performance

Tags: c++, windows, directx, desktop

I'm using Desktop Duplication to copy the contents of the screen to a bitmap in memory. I receive desktop texture, then create a staging texture, use `CopyResource` to copy the Desktop Texture into the Staging Texture, finally call `ID3D11DeviceContext::Map` to access the staging texture bits and copy them. Pretty much the same way as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27283837/825318

The problem is that `Map` call takes a lot of time - for large display resolutions such as 4K it can take up to a 100ms per call, which is unacceptably high as I need to ensure 30 fps speed.

Is there any way to get the content of the texture faster? If not, is there any way to supply my own mapping address pointer so the system copies the texture data there? Thanks

Comment: The [ID3D11DeviceContext::Map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476457(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation talks about performance penalty and suggests the appropriate strategies and the end of the page. One of them is to use the volatile pointer.

Comment: Thanks, however that applies only to write-only surfaces, while my task is to read data from the surface.

Answer (score 6):

Most probably the Map operation is waiting on the CopyResource to complete. You can use [GPUView](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~mdfisher/GPUView.html) to verify this. If this is the case then the recommended solution is to accept the latency in favor of framerate. The way to handle this is to keep at least 3 staging textures and rotate between them in the following manner:

frame#1 - start copy resource to staging texture #1

frame#2 - start copy resource to staging texture #2

frame#3 - start copy resource to staging texture #3 and map staging texture #1 to access data

frame#4 - start copy resource to staging texture #1 (old contents should already be saved) and map staging texture #2 to access data

This way you can keep 30 FPS but introduce ~130ms latency which is acceptable for most applications.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I need minimum latency, so your solution isn't really solving my issue, however it's a smart approach and GPUView seems to be a very useful utility. Thus I'm awarding the bounty to you.

Comment: If you want minimum latency then you basically need to synchronize the CPU with the GPU to guarantee that the texture is read as soon as it is copied. This means that the GPU and the CPU would not work parallel and this is exactly what you were seeing in your original question.

If I'm missing something then please let me know it looks like you are trying to satisfy two opposing requirements.

Comment: Could you show me how to synchronize the CPU and GPU in this manner?

Comment: You just need to do exactly what the original question was describing. Call the Map function for read and it will make sure that all the work is finished on the GPU essentially synchronizing the CPU with it.

Comment: But like he mentioned the map functions is taking a really long time for me. Is there any other way to synchronize the CPU and GPU that isn't as time consuming as the Map function?

Comment: The synchronization is the thing that takes time. The CPU needs to wait for the GPU to finish the rendering and copying work. You can't synchronize without paying the cost.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but because I am doing DXGI desktop duplication all the suggested methods here and those by Microsoft do not apply as there is no "render thread".

The solution however for both, which is far better then the other suggestions as it keeps latency to the absolute minimum is to try to map with `D3D11_MAP_FLAG_DO_NOT_WAIT` and check for `DXGI_ERROR_WAS_STILL_DRAWING`. You can do this in a tight loop and it won't stall the pipeline. To avoid consuming too much CPU time, put a sleep/delay into the loop.

Comment: Not sure what busy waiting for Map() to succeed does better or faster than just letting Map wait internally until the output buffer is ready.  The name D3D11_MAP_FLAG_DO_NOT_WAIT suggests that it would grant access to the incomplete volatile buffer while the GPU writes, but according to the docs it will just fail to return the pointer until the buffer has been completely filled.

Comment: I explained exactly why. The device pipeline literally stalls until the map is completed if you don't busy wait for it, the latency hit is huge. See the Looking Glass project (https://looking-glass.io), we have done extensive instrumentation to validate and prove this.

Comment: Changing the word "faster" to "latency" doesn't explain anything.  Busywaiting in a tight loop for another thread, core or processor to do something typically doesn't reduce the time/latency between wanting a result and receiving it, it just wastes time by not allowing the OS scheduler to hand over control to ones code the moment the result is ready. Using the polling check to decide between doing some other useful thing and getting the new data is meaningful though .

Comment: How about you go and test the code yourself and do some profiling. The throughput of all DirectX applications plummet if you allow the mapping to block, which decreases your capture throughput. Allowing the map to block causes some internal contention with DirectX which prevents applications from being able to add additional commands to the command queue for the GPU, thus stalling ALL pipelines system wide.